# In what table in EE1 are banned user IPs stored?

Tags: members, ee1, banned

I have a client, using EE1.6.8, that acquired a list of spammer IPs and added the list to Admin > Members > Banned Members.  I don't know what IPs were in that list, but whatever the case, the front end of the site is now blank and neither of us is able to log in as super admins to undo the change. So I'm looking to go into the database itself, find the offending IP list and remove it.  But I haven't managed to figure out in which table this list of banned members would be stored.  Can someone point me in the right direction so I can help my client restore his site?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That data is stored in the exp_sites table in the site_system_preferences column in a serialized array.

Comment: Excellent - thanks I found it. It's one monster of a list that was inserted and so I think it may have been too long for, and therein corrupted the array.  The serialized array ends with an IP number rather than the usual ;}